# ZF2 return inserted row

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I know I can get the just inserted row id with

`$this->tableGateway->getLastInsertValue();`

I was wondering whether it is possible to return the just inserted row as object?
Or do I have to make a query to the database with the new id?

Is this fine or against development best practises?

Thx I really appreciate your help and your experiences

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

- Yes you should query the database with the new id if you know that the data you inserted is in a way modified or different than what you inserted (for example if you let the database insert a timestamp or whatsoever to the record upon insertion).
- I personally don't think it is against best practices, however you should try and make everything as streamlined as possible. I don't know how your code is set up, but try to compartmentalise as much as you can so that you can reuse most of your code.

Personally I would use an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) instead of the Zend Framework 2 database features, but that all depends on what you need from it really